# Strange hex number in url

Tags: nginx, php

Some days ago I noticed strange behavior on my web server.

When I open my domain it sometimes redirects me to `mydomain.com/?<strange hex number>`. Everything is working fine, except the ? at the end of query string. In web server logs it looks like: `"GET /?22ed0080 HTTP/1.1" 200 112`. Where should I look and what can cause such weird thing to happen. I have not changed any config files on server, so I am really confused.

My system: `Freebsd, nginx + php-fpm`.

Comment: start with some rewrite logs and see why the url is being redirected

Comment: `"GET image1.jpg?8a0496a0 HTTP/1.1" 200 1019` it doesn't looks like redirect, as static files are also appended by that strange number

Comment: If you are not accessing them with query parameter, something must be adding it. If you have some thing like firebug you can see if you are getting some redirection adding this parameter